# Preventing paper towel waste by tightening the roll

Tags: bathroom

I work in a workshop, and share toilets with 25+ workers. When they dispense  paper towels the roll keeps spinning and some paper towel is wasted when it falls to the floor (5 or 6 squares at a time). So, we need to buy paper towels a lot to keep in stock.

I was planning to use a spring to hold a metallic piece against the paper towel to keep it from spinning out of control, but I am not sure because this isn't  so original and may be a bad idea.

How can I decrease the waste of paper towels in the bathroom? **(Without Electricity!)**

[image: toilet paper]
[image: This is very bad :(]

Comment: Buy a [paper towel dispenser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper-towel_dispenser). It's a tool designed for this problem.

Comment: buy higher quality paper towels so people don't need to use as much

Comment: There must be like a thousand of different paper towel dispensers not needing any electricity, Why lifehack it when it only costs a few bucks ? By the way, it looks like you're using regular paper towel in the toilets, be aware this might be more prone to clogging your toilets than usual toilet paper which dissolve much faster in the water.

Comment: @LaurentS. I know the thousand types are available, but I didn't buy this. If I find a good solution with using this, I would be more happy. By the way, we are not using paper towels, we have toilet papers to do so. The place is far from closets.

Comment: First aid would be to wrap an elastic around the rod to provide some friction, then investigate rubber tubes and superior products.

Comment: It's a shame that you're in a building full of supposedly intelligent people that could use the tools attached to the ends of their arms to prevent this from happening (i.e. this shouldn't need a life hack, just a level of paper dispensing competence slightly above that of a kitten/2 year old child)

Comment: Side hack, you could make your paper go twice or three times as far by sawing through the whole roll you have there, cutting it into two or three separate cylinders. No one should need a 12 inch by 12 inch sheet of paper to wipe a 1 inch by 1 inch area

Answer (score 4):

This has a built-in tension spring to get around just this problem.  As you can see from the image below, the disk on the side of the roll adds tension and keeps the roll from spinning endlessly.

[image]

[http://www.amazon.com/Simplehuman-Mount-Paper-Holder-Stainless/dp/B002YI653C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002YI653C)

Comment: Seems like this would work

Answer (score 3):

The spinning in my experience happens most when the rolls are half or more empty, then gravity will help and the lid/cover “brake” less. One of the holders in our house has the same problem as the model in the question.

We circumvent the problem by giving the roll one good squeeze, flattening the cardboard core. This prevents the “free spinning” without hampering regular tissue pulling. No modification or exchange of the paper holder required.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Me and my friend have been found a solution. The way is very basic and economical. The plastic spare is a part of 19LT water bottle. With only 8 screws, we can bring three woods together and put some glue for making strong each other. Now, nobody can hold lots of towel, it is limited by the plastic part.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also ask owner of the place (or whoever responsible for the toilets themselves) to buy and install such a dispenser:

[image: Toilet paper dispenser with hole in the middle]

The paper comes out of a small hole in the middle, one in a time, so there's no waste. I have this in my own workplace for several years now and it's really good, though sometimes the paper [get stuck](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/23742/toilet-paper-is-stuck-in-the-dispenser-any-way-to-reach-it).